Did Caesar comment on the intellectual curiosity of the Gauls?
On p.147 of Morgenthau's Politics Among Nations, he writes:

The trait of intellectual curiosity which Julius Caesar detected in the Gauls has remained throughout the ages a distinctive character of the French mind.

I looked it up but couldn't find any references. Where did Caesar make such a comment?

I take it there's no specific reference in Morgentheau? Then the obvious place to look would be Caesar's Commentaries on the Gallic War. He describes the learning of the druids and their absence among the Germans but I don't see an obvious reason for Morgentheau to read this that way.

Maybe Morgenthau is confusing Tacitus with Caesar, and the Germans with the Gauls?

I can't comment on the nature of curiosity (whether childish or intellectual), but the editors of the book Caesar: Gallic War, Books I-V:iIn the chapter on Transalpine Gaul, make the following observation(emphasis mine):

57 Characteristics of the Gauls The Gauls in general were of
greater stature than the Romans. Their complexion was fair their hair
a reddish blond. In dress they were especially fond of bright colors.
The chiefs decorated themselves with golden rings bracelets and
necklaces, though such ornaments were not unknown among other classes.
In temperament the Gauls were boastful, impulsive, and hasty in
forming resolves and plans, often disastrous in outcome. These
qualities were augmented by a childish curiosity and credulousness of
chance rumors and of stories told them by traders. In battle they
were courageous and impetuous but lacked staying qualities being
easily disheartened by defeat. They showed no little cleverness in
imitating the military contrivances of their enemies

So yes, curiosity was indicated.  Another hit on curiosity later in the same book ,Curiosity and temerity of the Gauls narrows down  where in Caesars' works this behavior might be indicated. This is the English introduction/explanation to Book 4, section 5 which follows in Latin.
The link provided by @ccprog would take us to the following translation of that section (emphasis mine):

Caesar, when informed of these matters, fearing the fickle disposition
of the Gauls, who are easily prompted to take up resolutions, and much
addicted to change, considered that nothing was to be intrusted to
them; for it is the custom of that people to compel travelers to stop,
even against their inclination, and inquire what they may have heard,
or may know, respecting any matter; and in towns the common people
throng around merchants and force them to state from what countries
they come, and what affairs they know of there. They often engage in
resolutions concerning the most important matters, induced by these
reports and stories alone; of which they must necessarily instantly
repent, since they yield to mere unauthorized reports; and since most
people give to their questions answers framed agreeably to their
wishes.

So the tendency of the Gauls to question random passersby and merchants would appear to be an indication of this curiosity.
What adjective (or opinion) you might apply to that curiosity, whether intellectual or childish, I would leave the reader.

This is a summary of Caesar, not Caesar's own words.

Since the link does not point to an accessible source, can you please note the number of the book and the paragraph? Or better yet, link to a source that is available online? I am unable to find your quote.

Correction: I was geo-blocked from accessing your link. But @cmw is right: your first quote cites the editors Johnston and Sanford, not Cesar.

Updated with Book and paragraph, and direct translation.

Can you explain how that passage remarks on the intellectual curiosity of the Gauls?

No. I imagine that is an expression of the bias of the writer, much as the childish phrase above expresses the bias of those writers, since I see no direct correlation in the translation provided to indicate any specific adjectives. Perhaps an expert in Latin (@cmw) might be able to offer a better understanding/insight or interpretation from the original Latin, but I cannot.

(Opinion) If I had to determine a difference between Childish Curiosity and Intellectual Curiosity, I would consider Childish as Why? Why? Why? and Intellectual as Who? What? Why? Where? and When? The behavior described seems to me more akin to the latter-basically gathering military intelligence from any foreigners encountered. But that would be my opinion which is irrelevant in a History answer.

I only ask because that's what OP asked for. I'd probably add that part into the answer for clarity's sake. I also think your intuition is correct: it's interrogation, not curiosity, that base desire (though I wouldn't label it childish per se) to learn about the world not for its own sake or to better oneself, but to morbidly learn of the gossip and happenings. (There might be a bit of irony here, but to make that on-topic, I'd have to dig a bit more into the surrounding narratives of Caesar's conquest.)
